# Replace Date-Code Sections of String

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date-formatted file name, e.g.

```
C:\Documents/<yyyy>\<MMM>\Example_CSV_<ddMM>.csv
```

and return "Todays" filename.

So for the example above, I would return (for 9th August 2013),
C:\Documents\2013\Aug\Example_CSV_0908.csv

I wondered if Regex would work, but I'm just having a mental block as to how to approach it!

I can't just replace the xth to yth sections with the date, as the files I will be processing are stored in different folders all over the system (not my idea). All of the date codes will be contained in <> however, so as far as I'm aware, I couldn't do something like

```
Return DateTime.Today.ToString(RawFileName);
```

Plus I imagine it would have unintended consequences if a part of the ordinary filename could be interpreted as a date code!

If someone could give me a pointer in the right direction, that would be great. If you need a little bit more context, here is the class that will contain this method:

```
public class ImportSetting
    {
        public string ID { get; private set; }
        public List<ImportMapping> Mappings { get; set; }
        public string RawFileName { get; set; }

        public string GetFileName() 
        {
            string ToFormat = RawFileName; //e.g. C:\Documents/<yyyy>\<MMM>\Example_CSV_<ddMM>.csv

            //Do some clever stuff.

            return ToFormat; //C:\Documents\2013\Aug\Example_CSV_0908.csv
        }
        public int GetCSVColumn(string AttributeName) { return Mappings.First(x => x.Attribute == AttributeName).ColumnID; }

        public ImportSetting(string Name)
        {
            ID = Name;
            Mappings = new List<ImportMapping>();
        }
    }
```

Thankyou very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var path = new Regex("<([dMy]+)>").Replace(pathFormat, o => DateTime.Now.ToString(o.Groups[1].Value));
```

Nb: Add all the possible letters/symbols that could occure within the square brackets.

Nb2: This will however not restrict weird DateTime strings. If you want to ensure a uniformed format, you could make a more restrictive Regex like so :

```
var path = new Regex("<(ddMM)|(MMM)|(yyyy)>").Replace(pathFormat, o => DateTime.Now.ToString(o.Groups[1].Value));
```

Edit: Gotta love one-liners :)

Comment: You are a genius. Hopefully I will be able to restrict errors by preventing them when the user inputs the filename and its saved to the XML file, rather than when I'm reading it back.

Out of interest, what would be an example of a date-time string that would cause an exception?

Comment: The one liner wouldn't cause an exception at all. He's refering to users inputing something like dMdM which isn't a proper sequence.

Comment: Yea, I just said that out of reflex. But it wouldnt cause exceptions. I'm editing the answer as we speak

Comment: I'd also change the regex to something like <([fdDmMyYs]+?)> since it allows for what ever date letter the users feel like. But you refered to that in your first Nb: already.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate Why the question mark? Wouldnt that make the format string within the < > option? Why would you want that? Also, you are missing more stuff in your format string like time dividers and such. That's why I didn't bother making a full list. I let it up to who ever wants to use it to choose what he allows

Comment: It's most likely not needed in all honesty, first regex I tested was \D so it made a string as long as possible starting with < and ending with > since the chance is small the rest of the string consists only of the fDYmM and other symbols I think you could do without. the ? after the + basically makes it "lazy" meaning it'll make the match as short as it possibly can.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to replace anything in the text as you can use the Date.ToString() method with a format string like this:

```
public string GetFileName(DateTime date)
{
    string format = @"'C:\\Documents'\\yyyy\\MMM'\\Example_CSV_'ddMM'.csv'";
    return date.ToString(format);
}
```

Call GetFileName with today's date:
`Console.WriteLine(GetFileName(DateTime.Now));`

Output:
`C:\Documents\2013\Aug\Example_CSV_0908.csv`

Anything that you don't want to be parsed as a date, put in single quotes `'` to have it parsed as a string literal. A full list of the date format strings can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion Matt! I don't know how I missed the literal string delimiter! I've updated my answer to include the literal string delimiter. I had to still escape the backslashes as those are special cases.

Comment: Looks better now.  I think the backslashes can go inside or outside the quotes and will work the same way.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (although I can't imagen this is a real scenario but that might be my lacking imagenation is the following regex;

```
<([fdDmMyYs]+?)>
```

This will give you any matches within the < and > symbols, as short as possible so in testing for me it returned;

Then strip the first and last symbol, or use some fancier regex functions to do this for you.

Then just use the DateTime.Now.ToString(RegexMatchWithout<> here)

And replace the match with the output.

So a code example (untested, but i'm feeling confident ;-)) would be:

```
public string GetFileName(string fileName) 
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<([fdDmMyYs]+?)>");

    foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(fileName))
    {
        fileName = fileName.Replace(m.Value, DateTime.Now.ToString(m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2)));
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the exact sort of thing I was looking for!

Only problem is, whilst it picks up all of the expressions that need to be matched, it doesn't replace anything...?

Comment: Made a silly typo, shoulnd't have felt that confident about my untested code. However it's better to use a StringBuilder rather then initializing a new string everytime and what not. It's functional code but there is room for improvement.